# How to write content of several files into a single one in Unix?

Tags: shell

Suppose in a directory there are some files like:

```
file1.txt  
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4
file5
fab
text1
```

I need to eliminate the files with the `.txt` extension and append the content of the remaining files having a file name started with **file**(`file4`, `file5`) to a single file.

I tried the below command, but it appends all 5 file content to a single file.

```
ls -ltr file*|grep -vE ".txt" | cat * > final
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `bash` available, you can use the following:

```
shopt -s extglob
cat !(*.txt) > final
```

Or using `zsh`:

```
setopt extended_glob
cat ^*.txt > final
```

Answer (score 0):

find . ! -name '*.txt' | xargs cat >> final

Comment: This version has a couple of downsides. 1) it's recursive, which may not be desired. 2) it will break on filenames that contain spaces. 3) the fact that it appends prevents running it twice and getting the same resulting file.

Comment: you can use find with -maxdepth 1 -type f parameters

Comment: That works, but not all versions of `find` support `-maxdepth` and OP did not specify his OS.

Comment: The solution using 'cat' is definitely better. On the other hand, the nice thing in Linux is that there are multiple ways of solving any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name '*.txt' -exec rm {} +

for f in file*
do
    cat $f >> final_file
done
```

In one line without removing `.txt` files but ignoring them for the `cat`

```
$ find . -name 'file*' ! -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \; > final
```